# How to query the geoname database?

Tags: mysql, geonames

I am trying to use the database on geonames.org, i inserted all the database files into an sql database.

Now i have a couple of database tables, one with country names, one the provinces/states, and one table with all the city's. The files on the geoname database are named as: countryinfo.txt, admin1codesascii.txt, admin2codes.txt, allcountries.txt.

Something i don't understand, is how do i use all these tables together to get a hierachy like country->province/states->city's? Because if i don't use the hierachy, the allcountries database is far to huge, to just select a city by name.. It takes 10 minutes.

What i am wanting to do is creating a  box, where all the countries are in. If they select a country, then i want to show in a second selectbox the provinces and states. But how do i select the provinces states, if there is nothing in common like an id, or a name in the admin1codes database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That totally depends on what you want with the data, and what exactly you want to query.

Have you taken a look at the readme.txt? You can find it here: http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/readme.txt

Also, this question is related, and should give you the correct answer: [Geonames database: getting a full hierarchy (country -> admin1 -> admin2 -> city) with one only mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7319820/geonames-database-getting-a-full-hierarchy-country-admin1-admin2-city)

Comment: Thanks, the link to the related question gives me a nice example of how to use the database. That exactly what i needed.

Comment: After i did some more research, this isn't exactly what i am looking for... :( And the readme file, doesn't contain much information about where the cells are exactly for, they only explain something about the allcountries.txt file. But they explain nothing about the admin1code etc.